# Why jQuery returning value of radio buttons as "ON"? How to correct it?

Tags: html, jquery, radio-button

I'm not absolutely novice but somehow it's caught me since an hour. Can you please help me by finding where I am making a mistake in the following piece? I'm trying to return value of the "checked/selected" Radio option and it is returning "on" every time.

My (Bootstrap) HTML Code:

```
<div class="form-row mb-4 p-2 text-center font-weight-bold rounded-top shadow-sm-dark no-shadow-hover bl__home_apr-choice">
    <div class="col-4 offset-2 col-md-3 offset-md-0 mb-md-0 mb-1">
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
        <input type="radio" id="searchByProject" name="searchBy" class="custom-control-input" checked="checked">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="searchByProject" value="Project" pointer>by Project</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 col-md-3 offset-md-0 mb-md-0 mb-1">
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
        <input type="radio" id="searchByInvoiceID" name="searchBy" class="custom-control-input">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="searchByInvoiceID" value="Invoice" pointer>by Invoice</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 offset-2 col-md-3 offset-md-0 mb-md-0">
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
        <input type="radio" id="searchByStartDate" name="searchBy" class="custom-control-input">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="searchByStartDate" value="Started" pointer>by Start Date</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 col-md-3 offset-md-0 mb-md-0">
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
        <input type="radio" id="searchByEndDate" name="searchBy" class="custom-control-input">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="searchByEndDate" value="Ended" pointer>by End Date</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And this is how I am using jQuery:

```
console.log($('input[name=searchBy]:checked').val());
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add a `value` attribute to each radio `<input type="checkbox" value="XXX"/>`

Comment: FYI `"on"` is the default value for radio buttons

Comment: Oh, that is the problem.. Thank you @charlietfl for pointing it out. It is a great and quick help from you. Thanks a ton! You been of great help. God bless you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the `value` in the `input` tag, you're doing it in the `label`.

Your radio should be like this:

```
<input type="radio" id="searchByEndDate" name="searchBy" value="Ended" checked>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... I just learned it from @charlietfl too a second back. It was silly mistake which I had made. Thanks again.